# Functional derivative or operator (of $f$) giving $\frac {f''}{f}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, soft-question, logarithms

We can derive the logarithmic derivative

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left\{\log(f(t))\right\} = \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$$

But can we similarly find some other function, so that:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left\{h(f(t))\right\} = \frac{f''(t)}{f(t)}$$

If it is impossible, how can we show it being impossible?

---

**Own work**
I first imagined something like...
$$h: f\to \frac{\partial \log(f'(t))  }{\partial t} \cdot \frac{\partial \log(f(t))}{\partial t} = \frac{f''(t)}{f(t)}$$

Now this is hardly a function in any normal sense, is it?

If it is not a function, then what to call it?

Comment: Did you mean $h(f')'$ or $h(f)''$? Because you obviously can not get the second derivative out of differentiating $f$ only once, even after composing it with something else.

Comment: One could also use $$\frac{f''}{f} = \frac{\partial^2 \log\left(f(t)\right)}{\partial t^2} + \left(\frac{\partial \log\left(f(t)\right)}{\partial t}\right)^2$$ which has the benefit of being quasilinear in the second logarithmic derivative (useful in cases where the second derivative is much larger than the first, e.g. $\log f(t) = t^{4/3}$ near $0$), not to mention it is only a functional of $f$ instead of both $f$ and $f'$, but perhaps there is some use for the chain rule like quantity you describe.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Aah thank you! you sound like you can answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461293/name-of-mathematical-object-which-can-do-second-order-logarithmic-derivative for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $h$ is a function such that $$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left\{h(f(t))\right\} = \frac{f''(t)}{f(t)}$$ holds for all $f$ then take $f(t)=t$ to see that  $$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left\{h(t))\right\} =0$$ which  means that $h$ is a constant. Hence there is no such function.

Comment: Wow, that was easier to prove than I thought. Then what can we call the thing above? The $h$ in my speculation which takes $f$ to product of it's and it's derivatives' logarithmic derivative and multiplies them?